# Artin's theorem for the linear representation of finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm studying the book of Serre, *Linear Representation of Finite Groups* and in the section 9.2 he states a theorem, "the Artin's theorem", which is:

> Let $G$ a finite group, $X$ a family of finite subgroups of $G$ and $$
> \operatorname{Ind}: 
> \bigoplus_{H \in X} R(H) \to R(G)
> $$
> for which each component is $\operatorname{Ind}_{H}^{G}: R(H) \to R(G)$. The following assertions are equivalent:
>
> - $G$ is the union of all conjugates of subgroups in $X$;
> - the cokernel of the morphism $\operatorname{Ind}$ is finite.

I understood the proof, but I don't see how it can be useful. Does someone see the utility of this theorem? Thank you.

Comment: Ok I see, thank you. So by tensorizing by the rational numbers, all characters on $G$ become linear combinations with rational coefficients of characters induced by subgroups. However, what do you mean by it is difficult to construct characters ? Or do you mean irreducible characters ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on Artin's theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_theorem_on_induced_characters, tells you the *actual* theorem Artin cared about proving: every character on a finite group $G$ is a rational combination of induced characters from cyclic subgroups.  This is a special case of the abstract Artin theorem you're puzzled by, using as $X$ the cyclic subgroups of $G$.

Of course this leads to the obvious question: why should anyone (like Artin)  care about the *actual* theorem Artin cared about proving?  His motivation came from trying to understand Artin $L$-functions, particularly to prove they are analytic on $\mathbf C$. That is a compelling motivation if you are interested in number theory, as Artin was, but otherwise it isn't. And that's how things developed historically.  What Artin really wanted was such an "induction theorem" with integral coefficients (ideally nonnegative integer coefficients, but nonnegativity is too much to expect in general).  Brauer later proved such a result: look up Brauer's induction theorem on characters. It implies all Artin $L$-functions are meromorphic on $\mathbf C$, which might seem equally obscure if you don't know enough number theory, but it was a major result and earned Brauer the AMS Cole prize in 1949. Artin’s induction theorem implies the weaker property that each Artin $L$-function has some *integral power* that is meromorphic on $\mathbf C$.

To see reasons someone might care about Brauer's theorem, look at Snaith's book *Explicit Brauer Induction: With Applications to Algebra and Number Theory*.

Comment: There is a short summary of Snaith's theory in Remark 10.23 of [Robert Boltje's notes on representation theory](https://boltje.math.ucsc.edu/courses/w19/w19m240anotes.pdf). For a quick answer to "what on earth is explicit Brauer induction", that seems unbeaten. Makes me wonder if there is a similarly simple proof of the formula... after all, it's just a Möbius function sum, right?

Comment: Ah, apparently the relevant formula is proved in Theorem 3.2 (a) of [Robert Boltje, *Identities in Representation Theory via Chain Complexes*, Journal of Algebra **167**, Issue 2, 15 July 1994, Pages 417--447](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1994.1193).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, unfortunately I never followed a course on Number Theory. I'm working in Representation Theory and Functors Categories.